# How can I execute Cloud Function directly?

Tags: bash, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, gcloud

I'm tring to execute cloud function directly as below, but there might be something wrong and encountered syntax error.

```
-- command
gcloud functions call(cf-pubsub --region=asia-northeast1) --data 
'{
  "data": {
    "bucket":"bucket_name",
    "name":"filename.json"
  }
}'

-- error
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('
bash: {
      "data": {
        "bucket":"bucket_name",
        "name":"filename.json"
      }
  }
}: No such file or directory
```

We have billion of target files in GCP and it takes too much time to read all blob_list so I'd like to execute them by command directly.

Is there any better way and right syntax, please advise me.

Comment: That message looks like your bash shell is complaining about the syntax you used on the command line.  Likely has nothing to do at all with gcloud or how it works.

Comment: You seem to run this code using bash, and since it is not bash code, you get a syntax error.

Comment: I have never worked with gcloud, but I feel that your code could be suitable for glcoud shell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The syntax you are following for the command is wrong. **call(cf-pubsub --region=asia-northeast1)** shouldn't be encapsulated with a brackets. Don't forget that you need to pass the --gen2 param if you are using Cloud Functions gen 2.

For your case it should be,

```
gcloud functions call cf-pubsub --region=asia-northeast1 --data '{
  "data": {
    "bucket":"bucket_name",
    "name":"filename.json"
  }
}'
```

You can access the documentation of the command you shared through the [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/functions/call). Such [documentation](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/running/direct#test_your_function_with) also helps you in writing your commands by just filling simple gaps.

Taking into consideration that you have a "billion of target files in GCP" to process, It would be a better approach to pass only the bucket name as a param to the Function, and the function would list and process the files one by one within a loop. Then, each processed file would need to be moved to another folder or bucket to keep it as a logger for the processed files. In cases where the Cloud Functions (gen2) 1-hour execution time is not enough, you can chain the function to be called again until the function returns the required/appropriate value.

Comment: Many, many thanks for your variable advice!! You saved my day!!